# CKAN PluginNotFoundException in Pages Extension

Tags: python, apache, exception, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal. It's written in Python using Pylons framework. I want to integrate [ckanext-pages](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages) plugin. So I used below steps.

```
1. . /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate

2. pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages.git#egg=ckanext-pages'

3. cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-pages

4. python setup.py develop
```

Still I get below exception. Given that I tried restart CKAN and Apache server.

```
ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: pages
```

But when I run the *python setup.py develop* command it still that plugin is install correctly. Please see the output below.

```
running develop
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running egg_info
writing ckanext_pages.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to ckanext_pages.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
writing top-level names to ckanext_pages.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to ckanext_pages.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to ckanext_pages.egg-info/entry_points.txt
WARNING: ckanext is a namespace package, but its __init__.py does
not declare_namespace(); setuptools 0.7 will REQUIRE this!
(See the setuptools manual under "Namespace Packages" for details.)

reading manifest file 'ckanext_pages.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'ckanext_pages.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ckanext-pages.egg-link (link to .)
Removing ckanext-pages 0.1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding ckanext-pages 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-pages
Processing dependencies for ckanext-pages==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for ckanext-pages==0.1
```

Even though it says that plugin is installed correctly, exception is occurred. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the packages into the system Python (/`usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`). Make sure that you use the pip and python from the virtualenv. It seems that the virtualenv is not activated at all. Try executing `source /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate`
You could also try to call pip and python with the absolute path of the virtualenv.

Comment: I tried executing source /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate then all above 4 command. Still the same exception occurs.