# How to add existing extension to CKAN main menu?

Tags: python, menu, pylons, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal. It's written in Python using Pylons framework. There is an Apps & Ideas page given by CKAN already. It can be accessed via http://data.myckan.com/related. Adding /related to the url will show the page.

How can add this as a menu item to CKAN main menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write your own, very simple, CKAN theme that just has one template that adds a link to the menu. See the theming tutorial: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming

Comment: Why can't I make the same change on the existing template?

Comment: Essentially that is what you would be doing - you would add a "theme" that contains only one template that contains only one template block that does only one thing: adds your custom menu item. The rest of the page and the site would still use the default or existing theme. (See the theming tutorial for a full explanation of how customizing the contents of CKAN pages works.)

Comment: If you can please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202185/ckan-pluginnotfoundexception-in-pages-extension

Comment: I went through this tutrotial. http://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/theming/index.html, But I don't get how to get this done. Can you please be kind enough to explain how to get this done. I just want to add the related to menu. That's all.